# OpenCV Android implementation with CMAKE undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*) Error

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, android-ndk, dlib

I am trying to implement OpenCV310 with CMAKE in Android. I am using dlib library and OpenCV library together. [Example project github link](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android/)

In this github link, its calling opencv methods in dlib library on Android NDK. I am trying to implement this project myself with CMAKE. I tried calling openCV from an simple native-lib.cpp file. And its working. But when i added the dlib it started gives the errors.

```
Error:(571) undefined reference to 'cv::fastFree(void*)'
Error:(682) undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::deallocate()'
```

This is my CMAKE file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(pathToProject C:/Users/lenovo/AndroidStudioProjects/AdviserOpenCV3)
set(pathToOpenCV C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/openCV310/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk)

set(JNI_DETECTION_INCLUDE src/main/jni/jni_detections)
set(JNI_DETECTION_SRC src/main/jni/jni_detections)
set(JNI_COMMON_INCLUDE src/main/jni)
set(JNI_COMMON_SRC src/main/jni/jni_common)
set(DLIB_DIR src/main/dlib)
set(EXT_DIR src/main/third_party)

include_directories(${pathToOpenCV}/sdk/native/jni/include)
#include_directories(${DLIB_DIR}  ${JNI_COMMON_INCLUDE} ${JNI_DETECTION_INCLUDE} include)

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

add_library(android_dlib SHARED
            ${JNI_DETECTION_SRC}/jni_face_det.cpp
            ${JNI_DETECTION_SRC}/jni_imageutils.cpp
            ${JNI_DETECTION_SRC}/jni_pedestrian_det.cpp
            ${JNI_COMMON_SRC}/jni_bitmap2mat.cpp
            ${JNI_COMMON_SRC}/jni_fileutils.cpp
            ${JNI_COMMON_SRC}/jni_utils.cpp
            ${JNI_COMMON_SRC}/rgb2yuv.cpp
            ${JNI_COMMON_SRC}/yuv2rgb.cpp
            ${DLIB_DIR}/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp
            ${DLIB_DIR}/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp
            ${DLIB_DIR}/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp
            ${DLIB_DIR}/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp
            ${DLIB_DIR}/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp
            ${EXT_DIR}/glog/logging.cc)


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   android_dlib
                   lib_opencv
                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   $\{log-lib} )
```

How can i solve this problem? Thank you for your contributions. 
Best Regards,

Comment: You can pick the **libopencv_java3.so** file from `${pathToOpenCV}/sdk/native/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so`, you don't need to copy it to **jniLibs**.

Comment: If you use OpenCV functions in `native-lib` library, then you should link given library with `lib_opencv`. But you link `android_dlib` one.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare dependency between **native-lib** and **lib_opencv**. You probably want **android_dlib** too:

```
target_link_libraries(
    native-lib
    android_dlib
    lib_opencv
   # Links the target library to the log library
   # included in the NDK.
    log )
```

As you can see above, you don't need **${log-lib}** in your script; Android NDK defines **log** library for you.

Comment: One of the source files for `android_dlib` is `${EXT_DIR}/glog/logging.cc`. I guess, this file uses logging functionality, so `android_dlib` by itself should be linked with `log`: `target_link_libraries(android_dlib log)`.